# Não consigo entender meu erro com o FOR e DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, for, dataframe

Estou com um problema no meu for, onde todos os resultados estão saindo como mesmo valor dentro da DataFrame, mas eu n consigo entender o erro, alguem poderia me ajudar

```
import pandas as pd

BRICS=pd.DataFrame({'País':["Brasil","Russia","India","China","Africa do Sul"],'Capital':['Brasilia','Moscou','Nova Deli','Beijing','Pretoria'],'Area':[8.516,17.100,3.286,9.597,1.221],'População':[200.40,143.50,1252.00,1357.00,52.98]})

print(BRICS,'\n')

for i in range(len(BRICS)):
  BRICS=BRICS.assign(Densidade=BRICS['População'].values[i]/BRICS['Area'].values[i])

print(BRICS)
```

Comment: já tentou fazer `BRICS['Densidade'] = BRICS['População'] / BRICS['Area']` ou  `BRICS.assign(Densidade=BRICS['População']/BRICS['Area'])` sem o `for` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, para ocupar a coluna `Densidade` você está criando a cada iteração do `for` um vetor que tem apenas o valor do cálculo de densidade para o elemento `i`. Como esse vetor tem um único elemento, ele é replicado por todas linhas do *data frame*.

O valor `43.390663` que seu código coloca é justamente o valor de `Densidade` para o último país do *data frame*.

Uma sugestão de código seria

```
import pandas as pd

BRICS=pd.DataFrame({'País':["Brasil","Russia","India","China","Africa do Sul"],'Capital':['Brasilia','Moscou','Nova Deli','Beijing','Pretoria'],'Area':[8.516,17.100,3.286,9.597,1.221],'População':[200.40,143.50,1252.00,1357.00,52.98]})

print(BRICS,'\n')

BRICS = BRICS.assign(Densidade = lambda x: BRICS['População'] / BRICS['Area'])

print(BRICS)
```

Ou seja: substituir seu laço `for` por uma expressão lambda que o Pandas aplicará a todos elementos do vetor.

Esta solução permitirá otimizações, caso o Panda consiga distribuir as invocações da expressão lambda entre vários processadores.

Comment: Parece que no exemplo mostrado `lambda x:` não esta sendo utilizada, talvez deva ser alterado para: `BRICS.assign(Densidade = lambda x: x['População'] / x['Area'])`

Comment: Seu comentário tem alguma dose de razão, caro Icaro. Aparentemente, quem editou a pergunta não observou isso.

Comment: Mas, perceba que, mesmo não havendo o uso de `x` no corpo da expresssão lambda, tudo se aplica ao *data frame* `BRICS`. Por isso é que o exemplo funcionou corretamente quando o executei.

Comment: Apenas comentando que ao verificar a [revisão de edições da resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/517022/revisions) não parece haver nenhuma modificação no código por parte dos editores. Ou seja, resposta foi criada com este código (a pergunta também).

Comment: Pois é: eu também não entendi qual foi a revisão feita. Ou para que foi feita.

Comment: O objetivo da edição é adequar a pergunta ao formato do site e não fazer correções no código. A correções de código são de responsabilidade do autor da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

A solução mais performática seria:

```
BRICS["Densidade"] = BRICS['População'] / BRICS['Area']
```

Usar `for`, `apply`, `assign` com o auxílio de uma função (nomeada ou lambda) é mais lento.

Para maiores detalhes veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)

Comment: De fato, sua solução parece fazer sentido, caro @Paulo Marques. Agradeço sua sugestão. Mas em uma *data frame* tão pequena como aquela apresentada, isto talvez não tenha grande impacto.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes, concordo com você no que diz respeito ao exemplo, mas o intuito nas perguntas é ter um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) tanto de código quanto de dados. Entendo que nossas respostas devam responder as perguntas, mas serem úteis para outros casos.

Comment: De acordo, @PauloMarques. Concordo que sua resposta -- muito bem escolhida -- leva em conta a vetorização que NumPy pode promover. Ainda assim, é sempre relevante poder comparar diversas alternativas. Raramente em tecnologia uma única solução resolve todos problemas.